# Allow user to rotate image with css & jquery

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, transform, drag

I want to allow user to rotate image like we do in photoshop, I have a created a fiddle.
Something feels wrong with rotation deg, struggling since long, requesting for some help.

Js Fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/madhuri2987/fZegT/8/

Full Screen - http://jsfiddle.net/madhuri2987/fZegT/8/embedded/result/

HTML

```
<div id="mainTarget">
    <img src="http://myreaxns.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/priyanka-chopra-image.jpg" width="300" class="mainTarget" />
    <div id="target">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(window).load(function(){
var dragging = false

$(function() {
    var target = $('#target');
    var mainTarget = $('#mainTarget');
    target.mousedown(function() {
        dragging = true
    })
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        dragging = false
    })
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        if (dragging) {

            var mouse_x = e.pageX;
            var mouse_y = e.pageY;
            var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - 10, mouse_y - 10);
            var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
            mainTarget.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            mainTarget.css('-moz-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
            mainTarget.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            mainTarget.css('-webkit-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
            mainTarget.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            mainTarget.css('-o-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
            mainTarget.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            mainTarget.css('-ms-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
        }
    })
})
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a newer jQuery v. you don't have to target all the **-browser-specific** properties.
 Use just `transform`.

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ifezoq/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
var dragging = false;
$(function() {
    var target = $('#target');
    var mainTarget = $('#mainTarget');
    var rad = mainTarget.width()/2;
    var elOfs = mainTarget.offset();
    var elPos = {
       x: elOfs.left,
       y: elOfs.top
    };
    target.mousedown(function() {
        dragging = true;
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        dragging = false;
    });
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {        
      if (dragging) {
        var mPos = {
          x: e.pageX-elPos.x,
          y: e.pageY-elPos.y
        };
        var getAtan = Math.atan2(mPos.x-rad, mPos.y-rad);
        var getDeg = -getAtan/(Math.PI/180) + 135;  //135 = (180deg-45deg)

        mainTarget.css({transform: 'rotate(' + getDeg + 'deg)'});
      }
    });
});
```

Ideally you could do something like this:

http://jsbin.com/ifezoq/2/edit

```
$(function() {
    var dragging = 0;
    var target     = $('#target');
    var mainTarget = $('#mainTarget');
    var elOfs = mainTarget.offset();
    var cent  = {X: mainTarget.width()/2, Y: mainTarget.height()/2};    
    var elPos = {X: elOfs.left, Y: elOfs.top};
    target.mousedown(function() {
        dragging = true;
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        dragging = 0;
    }).mousemove(function(e) {     
      if(dragging) {
         var mPos    = {X: e.pageX-elPos.X, Y: e.pageY-elPos.Y};
         var getAtan = Math.atan2(mPos.X-cent.X, mPos.Y-cent.Y);
         var getDeg  = -getAtan/(Math.PI/180) + 135; 
         mainTarget.css({transform: 'rotate(' + getDeg + 'deg)'});
      }
    });
});
```

but that would be in case you got a square image inside a circle, where the draggable corner is always at 45deg.
But as you can see the gap is to get the starting angle difference when handling rectangles, - you need to apply additional math, which is not needed if you ask me, so I suggest the first demo.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, modified script to the one below:

Fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/madhuri2987/fZegT/9/

JS

```
$(window).load(function(){
var dragging = false

$(function() {
    var target = $('#target');
    var mainTarget = $('#mainTarget');
    var offset = mainTarget.offset();
    target.mousedown(function() {
        dragging = true
    })
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        dragging = false
    })
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        if (dragging) {

            var center_x = (offset.left) + (mainTarget.width()/2);
            var center_y = (offset.top) + (mainTarget.height()/2);
            var mouse_x = e.pageX; var mouse_y = e.pageY;
            var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
            var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 120;    
            mainTarget.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            mainTarget.css('-moz-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
            mainTarget.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            mainTarget.css('-webkit-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
            mainTarget.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            mainTarget.css('-o-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
            mainTarget.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
            mainTarget.css('-ms-transform-origin', '50% 50%');
        }
    })
})
});
```

If anyone thinks Im wrong and there is a better way of doing this then please do tell me.. Thanks :)

Comment: Remember that you get `120` manually by pure *coincidence* so to say, 120 will depend on the image X-Y ratio cause the draggable angle is not always at exactly 45deg positon. :)